# Why is centering a TikZ picture from an external file not the same as a centering a .png figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment, external-files

Why can't I put a Tikz picture inside `\makebox`?

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{./Figures/chapter5/procedure_contacts.pdf}}
\end{figure}
```

is OK, but a TikZ file which compiles perfectly on its own using `standalone` doesn't in the above environment, that is, `\input{tikz_figure.tex}`

Comment: the `\makebox` isn't doing anything useful in your example, you could just use `\centering`. If you have a problem with a tikz figure you should make a _complete_ minimal working example that shows the problem. Perhaps your tikz picture is wider than the page? Impossible to guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have seen the `\makebox` trick being used when the width of the graphic is larger than `\textwidth`.

Comment: @Aditya yes sure, but unless my maths has completely failed me `width=.8\textwidth` is unlikely to be bigger than `\textwidth` :-)

Comment: So are you saying you can't use a `\makebox` environment for a tikzpicture? It just complains saying \end{tikzpicture} even though this particular picture compiles flawlessly on its own in standalone

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah yes but can I include the argument `width=.8\textwidth` within `\input{some_tikzpicture.tex}`somehow? Tikz picture will compile within just the figure environment but NOT within \makebox, this is the crux of my problem. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Without a full MWE, this is I'm afraid 'unclear'.